# How to add a check box and a multicolumn combo controls in DevXpress Grid Control?

Tags: devexpress, multiple-columns

Is it possible to add check box, multi-column combo controls in DevXpress Grid Control? Could anyone guide me on this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The grid control enables you to assign different types of in-place editors to data cells.
You can find a detailed explanation here:  [In-place Editors Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument745)